# Получение IMEI телефона Android в приложении Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, c#, xamarin, forms

Вопрос неоднократно поднимался на форумах, но работающего решения на C# я так и не нашел. Данную часть API разработчики из Android переделали, поэтому на современных версиях API решения предложенные в 2015 году уже не работают.

Собственно, решается через обращение к Android TelephonyManager:

```
public class UniqueIdAndroid : IDevice
{
    public string GetIdentifier()
    {
        string deviceId = "";
        var context = MainActivity.Instance;
        if (context == null)
            return deviceId;

        var manager = TelephonyManager.FromContext(context);

        if (manager.GetDeviceId(1) != null)
        {
            deviceId = manager.GetDeviceId(1);
        }
        else
        {
            //deviceId = Secure.GetString(context.GetContentResolver(), Secure.AndroidId);
        }
        return deviceId;
    }
}
```

При этом необходимо выставить в манифесте приложения разрешение: READ_PHONE_STATE

Но, как выяснилось этим проблема не решается. При запуске приложение вылетает с исключением:
Unhandled Exception:
Java.Lang.SecurityException: 
При повторном запуске:
Unhandled Exception:
Java.Lang.SecurityException: getDeviceId: Neither user 10117 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.

При дальнейшем изучении обнаружил, что в Android начиная с версии 6.0 и выше необходимо запросить права доступа во время выполнения программы. Нашел [пример кода на Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742327/neither-user-10102-nor-current-process-has-android-permission-read-phone-state), но переделать его на C# пока не получилось. Может кто-нибудь подскажет как это реализовать на C#?

Кстати, закомментированная строчка тоже не работает. Как её подкорректировать и нужна ли она вообще?

Comment: Хочу уточнить, у вас проект на Xamarin.Forms или Xamarin.Android?

Comment: Проект на Xamarin.Forms

Comment: Функцию GetIdentifier() вы как вызываете? Через DepedencyService?

Comment: Да. (App.Current as App).DeviceID = DependencyService.Get<IDevice>().GetIdentifier();

Comment: Для запроса прав доступа попробуйте данную библиотеку: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.Permissions